# Recommended web.config encryption

Tags: c#, encryption, web-config

We would like to encrypt the web.config file in our servers that are in a cluster environment. I'm seeing various options to encrypt the web.config file. But I'm not sure which one is best practice or recommended option:

1. Do we have to encrypt the file in each server?
2. Is there an option to encrypt in one server and copy the encrypted file to all other servers? (something like RSA key container ... https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2w117ede(v=vs.100).aspx)
3. What are the security risks if we have same machine key in all the servers in farm?

Comment: If it is encrypted and then how would your application will read that config?

Comment: Unless the two servers use the same encryption key, your copy over approach won't work. The security risk is that once one server is hacked, all others will be hacked too, as the encryption key is the same.